# Animation in android is adding space

Tags: react-native, animation

Hi am trying to achieve an cubic transition of flatlist items similar to Zara app home screen. in iOS its working correctly but in android its taking space after each scroll.

This is the piece of code am using for transition

```
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
  const [pause, setPause] = React.useState(true);

  const ratio = 2;
  const perspective = height / ratio;
  const offset = height * index;
  const A = Math.asinh(perspective / ((height + 0) / 2));
  const inputRange = [offset - height, offset + height];
  const translateY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [-height / ratio, height / ratio],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const rotateY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [`-${A}rad`, `${A}rad`],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  const translateY1 = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [height / ratio, -height / ratio],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
 <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [
            {perspective},
            {translateY: translateY},
            {rotateX: rotateY},
            {translateY: translateY1},
            // {translateY: translateX2},
          ],
        }}>
    {my image with full width & height}

   </Animated.View>
```